# Looping through nested stacks in Swift

Tags: swift, for-loop, uiview

I want to be able to change the color on buttons in iOS which are inside of an arbitrary number of Horizontal stacks which are inside of a single vertical stack.

I was thinking to do something like this

```
for view in self.view.subviews as [UIView] {
    if let hstack = view as? UIStackView {
        for btn in hstack.arrangedSubviews {
            if let btn = view as? UIButton {
                btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting a warning line

> "Immutable value 'btn' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 constants named `btn`.  The first is created by the `for` loop, the second is created by the `if let`.  The `for` loop `btn` is not used.

I would suggest writing your code like this:

```
for case let hstack as UIStackView in self.view.subviews {
    for case let btn as UIButton in hstack.arrangedSubviews {
        btn.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

This uses patterns to select specific types of items from the arrays.  The first loop selects only those subviews that are of type `UIStackView`.  The inner loop selects only those arranged subviews that are of type `UIButton`.

Comment: Thank you!!!! worked like a charm. I'll have to read up on "for case" I haven't seen that before